# How to get permission associated with view programmatically

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-permissions

In Django I have a function that provides a list of all URL Patterns for my system. I am attempting to create a search feature that shows users links to a list of urls that they have permissions to view, but I cannot seem to figure out how to grab the associated permission from the view function.

How can I do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
def get_url_patterns():
    from django.apps import apps


    list_of_all_urls = list()
    for name, app in apps.app_configs.items():
        mod_to_import = f'apps.{name}.urls'
        try:
            urls = getattr(importlib.import_module(mod_to_import), "urlpatterns")
            list_of_all_urls.extend(urls)
        except ImportError as ex:
            # is an app without urls
            pass

    for thing in list_of_all_urls:
        # print(type(thing))
        # print(type(thing.callback.__name__))
        print(thing.callback.__dict__)

    return list_of_all_urls
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey there are many mays to do it

1. Use already build decorator

   from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required,user_passes_test

   User it as 
   @user_passes_test(lambda u: Model.objects.get(condition) in queryset)
2. You can make your own decorator

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
   user_login_required = user_passes_test(lambda user: user.is_active, login_url='/')

```
def active_user_required(view_func):
         decorated_view_func = login_required(user_login_required(view_func))
         return decorated_view_func
@active_user_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

List item

Comment: I would down vote this normally: I'm not certain your answer relates to my question. I have permission decorators on all of my views, some built in and some custom built, this is how permissions are best implemented in views for Django in my experience. What I need is each view's associated permissions based on the grabbed URL patterns so I can check to see if the current request.user has permission to access the view. I have currently created a solution for this that hardcodes my permissions to search but I want a more automated solution as scaling that feature seems taxing